# C# call method of a class object inside another class object

Tags: c#, object, methods

I am new to C# and am having trouble calling methods of a class object that is inside of another class object. I get an error saying that 'MainWindow.Mascot.MyNameIs()' is inaccessible due to its protection level.  However, all of the classes are public.  How can I call a class method of an object from inside another object?

Thanks!

Here is part of the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class Mascot
    {
        string name;

        string MyNameIs()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public class School
    {
        public Mascot myMascot;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        School Houston = new School();
        Houston.myMascot = new Mascot();
        Houston.myMascot.MyNameIs();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. public class does not mean the class's member is public; it is about to another scope.
   You have to attach public front of the function MyNameIs.

Try this.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class Mascot
    {
        string name;

        public string MyNameIs() // changed
        {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public class School
    {
        public Mascot myMascot;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        School Houston = new School();
        Houston.myMascot = new Mascot();
        Houston.myMascot.MyNameIs();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your modifier of method `MyNameIs()` is private because u dont define it. Just add acess modifier `public` like:

```
public string MyNameIs()
{
   return name;
}
```

If the class is not nested within another class, then its default access modifier is `internal`.If the class is nested within another class default access specifier is `private`.